# Using ReactiveUI for pass-through values in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

I've got a problem that I'm fairly sure ReactiveUI will help with but I can't quite wrap my brain around how to implement it. Basically I have a simple model:

```
public class Model
{
    public bool IsThingEnabled { get; set; }
    public string MyStringSetting { get; set; }

    public bool IsModified { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have a ViewModel that can edit this model, or swap out the model for a completely different one.

So it has the `IsThingEnabled` and `MyStringSetting` properties but also a `Model` field/property. Before my approach was to have a property getter and setter pass down to the underlying model, with some extra logic on the setters to update other dependent fields on the `Model`, set its `IsModified` to true, raise property changed event(s) and persist the model to disk.

This works pretty well, but the problem is that I have to raise a property changed event on *every* property when I swap out for a new `Model`, and it's easy to forget. I was thinking I could use ReactiveUI to streamline this in some manner but so far I haven't come up with anything. I thought about making an `Observable` and using `ObservableAsPropertyHelper` but that is apparently geared toward properties with only a getter.

Then I considered using a standard property with a backing store on the VM and a setter with `RaiseAndSetIfChanged`, but I couldn't figure out quite what `Observables` or subscriptions to do. I can observe a new `Model` getting set, but then would still be in the position where I need to distribute property change notifications for everything. And I'd still need to set up subscriptions to pipe each VM property down to the model when it's changed.

Am I missing something about ReactiveUI or should I use a different approach?

Comment: This should be possible, can you expand your class definitions to exclude the parent/child model property for clarity?

Comment: Well I eventually figured out it but it's a _little_ bit complex. I ended up with a helper function that encapsulates everything I wanted the VM setter to do. You can register a property which lets you hook secondary changes up and allows you to raise the PropertyChanged event for all of them when the model itself is changed. In the helper function it enforces registration to make sure you don't forget a property. If there's interest I'll post out the whole gory thing.